# Mongodb insert with where condition

Tags: mongodb

Do we have any way to do insert if where condition (passed) in mongoDb.

it's like from sql:
`insert into .... where not exits(select ....).`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/):

```
{ $merge: {
     into: <collection> -or- { db: <db>, coll: <collection> },
     on: <identifier field> -or- [ <identifier field1>, ...],  // Optional
     whenMatched: "keepExisting", 
     whenNotMatched: "insert"
} }
```

Comment: thank Wernfried, any options for mongo version bellow 4.2

Comment: No, unless you process results line by line with `forEach()`

Comment: im trying to dont use forEach that can be 2 thing todo in that (query to check -> do insert if passed). im afraid DB being changed between query and insert so i try todo in 1 transaction.